# Modifier factory functions should not be marked as @Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have created an extension function for Modifier that will show a BalloonPopup to the user when clicked. I am using @Composable tag for this function because the content i will be showing inside the Balloon is also @Composable. However the compiler gives me the warning below;

"*Modifier factory functions should not be marked as @Composable, and should use composed instead*"

I have also applied the suggested change, but then the balloon simply not shown when user clicks on the view.

My questions are;

1. Why *Modifier factory functions should not be marked as @Composable* ?
2. What is the difference between using @Composable and composed { ... } for such an extension function. Because for the time being, i haven't seen any downside using @Composable tag
3. Why the Balloon is not shown, even the code passes the if (showTooltip) condition when i debug my code.

Below are the codes for the function i used, both before and after the suggestion is applied;

Before:

```
@Composable
fun Modifier.setPopup(enabled: Boolean = false, content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit): Modifier {
    if (enabled) {
        var anchorOffset by remember { mutableStateOf<LayoutCoordinates?>(null) }
        var showTooltip by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        if (showTooltip) {
            BalloonPopup(
                onDismissRequest = {
                    showTooltip = false
                },
                content = content,
                anchorCoordinates = anchorOffset
            )
        }
        return this.clickable {
            showTooltip = true
        }.onGloballyPositioned {
            anchorOffset = it
        }
    } else {
        return this
    }
}
```

After:

```
fun Modifier.setPopup(enabled: Boolean = false, content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit): Modifier = composed {
    if (enabled) {
        var anchorOffset by remember { mutableStateOf<LayoutCoordinates?>(null) }
        var showTooltip by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        if (showTooltip) {
            BalloonPopup(
                onDismissRequest = {
                    showTooltip = false
                },
                content = content,
                anchorCoordinates = anchorOffset
            )
        }
        this.clickable {
            showTooltip = true
        }.onGloballyPositioned {
            anchorOffset = it
        }
    } else {
        this
    }
}
```

This is how i call the extension function;

```
Image(
   modifier = Modifier
                .setPopup(enabled = true) {
                    Text(
                         modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                         text = "-30 rssi",
                         fontSize = 13.sp
                    )
                },
   painter = painterResource(id = android.R.drawable.ic_secure),
   contentDescription = "Signal Strength"
)
```

And this is the BalloonPopup class that is used inside the extension function;

```
suspend fun initTimer(time: Long, onEnd: () -> Unit) {
    delay(timeMillis = time)
    onEnd()
}

@Composable
fun BalloonPopup(
    cornerRadius: Float = 8f,
    arrowSize: Float = 32f,
    dismissTime: Long = 3,
    onDismissRequest: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    anchorCoordinates: LayoutCoordinates? = null,
    content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit
) {
    if (anchorCoordinates != null) {
        var arrowPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(BalloonShape.ArrowPosition.TOP_RIGHT) }

        /**
         * copied from AlignmentOffsetPositionProvider of android sdk and added the calculation for
         * arrowPosition
         * */
        class BalloonPopupPositionProvider(
            val alignment: Alignment,
            val offset: IntOffset
        ) : PopupPositionProvider {
            override fun calculatePosition(
                anchorBounds: IntRect,
                windowSize: IntSize,
                layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
                popupContentSize: IntSize
            ): IntOffset {
                // TODO: Decide which is the best way to round to result without reimplementing Alignment.align
                var popupPosition = IntOffset(0, 0)

                // Get the aligned point inside the parent
                val parentAlignmentPoint = alignment.align(
                    IntSize.Zero,
                    IntSize(anchorBounds.width, anchorBounds.height),
                    layoutDirection
                )
                // Get the aligned point inside the child
                val relativePopupPos = alignment.align(
                    IntSize.Zero,
                    IntSize(popupContentSize.width, popupContentSize.height),
                    layoutDirection
                )

                // Add the position of the parent
                popupPosition += IntOffset(anchorBounds.left, anchorBounds.top)

                // Add the distance between the parent's top left corner and the alignment point
                popupPosition += parentAlignmentPoint

                // Subtract the distance between the children's top left corner and the alignment point
                popupPosition -= IntOffset(relativePopupPos.x, relativePopupPos.y)

                // Add the user offset
                val resolvedOffset = IntOffset(
                    offset.x * (if (layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr) 1 else -1),
                    offset.y
                )
                popupPosition += resolvedOffset

                arrowPosition =
                    if (anchorBounds.left > popupPosition.x) {
                        BalloonShape.ArrowPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                    } else {
                        BalloonShape.ArrowPosition.TOP_LEFT
                    }

                return popupPosition
            }
        }

        var isVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

        AnimatedVisibility(visible = isVisible) {
            Popup(
                popupPositionProvider = BalloonPopupPositionProvider(
                    alignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
                    offset = IntOffset(
                        x = anchorCoordinates.positionInParent().x.roundToInt(),
                        y = anchorCoordinates.positionInParent().y.roundToInt() + anchorCoordinates.size.height
                    )
                ),
                onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentSize()
                        .shadow(
                            dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.cardview_default_elevation),
                            shape = BalloonShape(
                                cornerRadius = cornerRadius,
                                arrowSize = arrowSize,
                                arrowPosition = arrowPosition,
                                anchorCoordinates = anchorCoordinates
                            )
                        )
                        .border(
                            Dp.Hairline, CCTechAppDefaultTheme.primary,
                            shape = BalloonShape(
                                cornerRadius = cornerRadius,
                                arrowSize = arrowSize,
                                arrowPosition = arrowPosition,
                                anchorCoordinates = anchorCoordinates
                            )
                        )
                        .background(
                            shape = BalloonShape(
                                cornerRadius = cornerRadius,
                                arrowSize = arrowSize,
                                arrowPosition = arrowPosition,
                                anchorCoordinates = anchorCoordinates
                            ),
                            color = CCTechAppDefaultTheme.surface
                        )
                        .padding(top = arrowSize.toDP())
                ) {
                    content()
                }
            }
        }

        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
            isVisible = true
            coroutineScope.launch {
                initTimer(dismissTime * 1000) {
                    isVisible = false
                    (onDismissRequest ?: {}).invoke()
                }
            }
        })

    }
}

class BalloonShape(
    private val cornerRadius: Float,
    private val arrowSize: Float,
    var arrowPosition: ArrowPosition = ArrowPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
    private val anchorCoordinates: LayoutCoordinates
) : Shape {

    enum class ArrowPosition {
        TOP_LEFT, TOP_RIGHT
    }

    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {
        val balloonLeft = 0f
        val balloonRight = size.width
        val balloonTop = 0f + arrowSize
        val balloonBottom = size.height

        val arrowTopY = 0f
        val arrowTopX =
            if (arrowPosition == ArrowPosition.TOP_LEFT) balloonLeft + anchorCoordinates.size.width / 2
            else balloonRight - anchorCoordinates.size.width / 2
        val arrowLeftX = arrowTopX - (arrowSize / 2f)
        val arrowLeftY = arrowTopY + arrowSize
        val arrowRightX = arrowTopX + (arrowSize / 2f)
        val arrowRightY = arrowTopY + arrowSize


        val path = Path().apply {
            moveTo(
                x = arrowTopX,
                y = arrowTopY
            )           // Start point on the top of the arrow
            lineTo(
                x = arrowLeftX,
                y = arrowLeftY
            )     // Left edge of the arrow
            lineTo(
                x = balloonLeft,
                y = balloonTop
            )                         // TopLeft edge of the rectangle
            arcTo(
                rect = Rect(
                    left = balloonLeft,
                    top = balloonTop,
                    right = balloonLeft + cornerRadius * 2f,
                    bottom = balloonTop + cornerRadius * 2f
                ),
                startAngleDegrees = 270f,
                sweepAngleDegrees = -90f,
                forceMoveTo = false
            )
            lineTo(
                x = balloonLeft,
                y = balloonBottom
            )                     // Left edge of the rectangle
            arcTo(
                rect = Rect(
                    left = balloonLeft,
                    top = balloonBottom - cornerRadius * 2f,
                    right = balloonLeft + cornerRadius * 2f,
                    bottom = balloonBottom
                ),
                startAngleDegrees = 180f,
                sweepAngleDegrees = -90f,
                forceMoveTo = false
            )
            lineTo(
                x = balloonRight,
                y = balloonBottom
            )                 // Bottom edge of the rectangle
            arcTo(
                rect = Rect(
                    left = balloonRight - cornerRadius * 2f,
                    top = balloonBottom - cornerRadius * 2f,
                    right = balloonRight,
                    bottom = balloonBottom
                ),
                startAngleDegrees = 90f,
                sweepAngleDegrees = -90f,
                forceMoveTo = false
            )
            lineTo(
                x = balloonRight,
                y = balloonTop
            )                     // Right edge of the rectangle
            arcTo(
                rect = Rect(
                    left = balloonRight - cornerRadius * 2f,
                    top = balloonTop,
                    right = balloonRight,
                    bottom = balloonTop + cornerRadius * 2f
                ),
                startAngleDegrees = 0f,
                sweepAngleDegrees = -90f,
                forceMoveTo = false
            )
            lineTo(
                x = arrowRightX,
                y = arrowRightY
            )     //  TopRight edge of the rectangle
            close()
        }
        return Outline.Generic(path)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @PylypDukhov, i have updated the question, please check again when you have time. I can provide more details if needed. Thanks for the guidelines link, i will check it in more detail and try to understand what is wrong with my code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `composable` to build modifiers is no longer [suggested](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/custom-modifiers#create_a_custom_modifier_using_a_composable_modifier_factory), so this warning shouldn't appear in new Compose versions.

Note that you still should be careful, with not adding any views to view hierarchy, and only use composable scope to storing/animating data.

---

According to Compose modifier guidelines:

> As a result, Jetpack Compose framework development and Library development **SHOULD** use `Modifier.composed {}` to implement composition-aware modifiers, and **SHOULD NOT** declare modifier extension factory functions as `@Composable` functions themselves.

Why

> Composed modifiers may be created outside of composition, shared across elements, and declared as top-level constants, making them more flexible than modifiers that can only be created via a `@Composable` function call, and easier to avoid accidentally sharing state across elements.

Using a view inside a modifier is kind of hacky. The modifier should change the state of the view to which it is applied, and should not affect the environment.

Your code works with `@Composable` because it is called instantly, and the popup is added to the view tree as if it had been added before the calling view.

With `composed`, the content is called later, when it starts measuring the view's position before render - since this code is not part of the view tree, your popup is not added to it.

The `composed` code is used so that you can save state with `remember` and also use local values such as `LocalDensity`, but not for adding views.

You can do almost anything you want in your codebase, after all, you can silence this warning, but most people who see your code won't expect such the modifier adding a view in the view tree - that's what guidelines are for.

I think the expected way to implement such a feature is as follows (not sure about the naming, through):

```kotlin
@Composable
fun BalloonPopupRequester(
    requesterView: @Composable (Modifier) -> Unit,
    popupContent: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit
) {
    var anchorOffset by remember { mutableStateOf<LayoutCoordinates?>(null) }
    var showTooltip by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    if (showTooltip) {
        BalloonPopup(
            onDismissRequest = {
                showTooltip = false
            },
            content = popupContent,
            anchorCoordinates = anchorOffset
        )
    }
    requesterView(
        Modifier
            .clickable {
                println("clickable")
                showTooltip = true
            }
            .onGloballyPositioned {
                anchorOffset = it
            }
    )
}
```

Usage:

```
BalloonPopupRequester(
    requesterView = { modifier ->
        Image(
            modifier = modifier,
            painter = painterResource(id = android.R.drawable.ic_secure),
            contentDescription = "Signal Strength"
        )
    },
    popupContent = {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
            text = "-30 rssi",
            fontSize = 13.sp
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: I see, so you suggest using a manager-like composable function to attach the popup to desired view and also hold the state for it inside the same function to dismiss etc. Instead of using an extender function for Modifier. Thanks for the code sample, that is helpful.

Comment: also, from these two sentences of yours;

"With composed, the content is called later, when it starts measuring the view's position before render - since this code is not part of the view tree, your popup is not added to it.

The composed code is used so that you can save state with remember and also use local values such as LocalDensity, but not for adding views."

I shouldn't even bother using composed for adding views, because that is not what they are used for ?

Comment: @caneru That's right, inside `composed` you should not add any views. I think there should be a warning, but it is probably impossible to distinguish between what is a view and what is a state, since both are annotated Composable

Comment: Your explanation is as obscure as the documentation. I wonder if you had played a part in documentation :)

Comment: Isn't `composed { }` deprecated?

Comment: @Mark I don't think so

Comment: @PhilDukhov https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/custom-modifiers#create_a_custom_modifier_using_a_composable_modifier_factory

Comment: @Mark thank you! interesting, I wonder why they haven't really deprecated `composed` with this update.