# How can you create a reusable modifier in Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Most of my screens(views) start out with a Box composable to contain all the child composables(components).

```
// background
Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(customColor)
    ) 
{
// foreground
Column()

}
```

Instead of having to create the modifier properties on every screen, how would you create a reusable modifier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In such a simple case, you can do the following (no need to use `then`):

```
fun Modifier.myModifier(customColor: Color) =
    this.fillMaxSize()
        .background(customColor)
```

In case you need to save any state in your modifier using `remember` or other state builders annotated with `@Composable`, you can do it with [Modifier.composed](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).composed(kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1)). For example here's how you can add animation to your modifier:

```
fun Modifier.myModifier(customColor: Color): Modifier = composed {
    val animatedColor by animateColorAsState(customColor)
    this.fillMaxSize()
        .background(animatedColor)
}
```

Note, that inside `composed` you should only use state annotated composables, not views. More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71913669/3585796).

Answer (score 1):

You can create it like this

```
fun Modifier.myModifier(customColor: Color) = this.then(
    Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(customColor)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use this approach:

1. Create separate file with modifiers, e.g. `Paddings.kt`

```
val firstItemOnScreenPaddingModifier = Modifier.padding(top = 24.dp, start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
fun Modifier.firstItemOnScreenPadding(): Modifier = this.then(firstItemOnScreenPaddingModifier)

val textFieldPaddingModifier = Modifier.padding(top = 6.dp, start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
fun Modifier.textFieldPadding(): Modifier = this.then(textFieldPaddingModifier)
```

2. Use like this:

```
Text(text = "test", modifier = firstItemOnScreenPaddingModifier)
```

or like this then you need more complicated modifier:

```
Text(
    text = "test", 
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(24.dp)
        .firstItemOnScreenPaddingModifier()
        .background(color = Color.White)
)
```